# How to test content of <Text /> tag in Jest + Enzyme + React Native?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme, react-native-text

I want to unit test with Jest and Enzyme if my `<Text />` tag correctly receives `props.header` as text.

Usually I was able to test the content of the `<Text />` tag like this:

```
it("should render a label", () => {
  expect(wrapper.find(Text).contains("submit")).toBe(true);
});
```

But as soon as I pass an object this is no longer possible. Let me show you:

```
const createTestProps = props => ({
  header: SOME_CONSTANT,
  ...props
});

...

  let wrapper;
  let props;
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = createTestProps();
    wrapper = shallow(<MyList {...props} loaded={false} />);
  });

  it("should render a header", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Text).contains(props.header)).toBe(true);
  });
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
● MyList › rendering › still loading › should render a header

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false
```

How could I test this using Jest and Enzyme?

### Edit

I found out that it has something to do passing a constant to the `props`. If I hardcode the value of `props` like this:

```
const createTestProps = props => ({
  header: "Some hardcoded value",
  ...props
});
```

The test also passes. Is there a way to make this work even with a constant?

Comment: If SOME_CONSTANT is a string variable, it should behave exactly the same. I wonder if the contents of SOME_CONSTANT are different from what you expect. Can you share a whole file that reproduces the error?

Comment: @stone unfortunately I can't, because of a busy schedule. But the constant is literally just defined like this: `SOME_CONSTANT="This is the text."` and it's being imported correctly (since I can console.log it).